# Unity Camera Follow 2D stutter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Now, I've been having a lot of issues with this, and I've been using the base Unity code that they provide as part of their 2D assets pack, and can be seen as follows below:
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class Camera2DFollow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float damping = 1;
public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;
public float yPosRestriction = -1;

float offsetZ;
Vector3 lastTargetPosition;
Vector3 currentVelocity;
Vector3 lookAheadPos;

float nextTimeToSearch = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lastTargetPosition = target.position;
    offsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
    transform.parent = null;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (target == null) {
        FindPlayer ();
        return;
    }

    // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
    float xMoveDelta = (target.position - lastTargetPosition).x;

    bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

    if (updateLookAheadTarget) {
        lookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor * Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
    } else {
        lookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(lookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime * lookAheadReturnSpeed);  
    }

    Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + lookAheadPos + Vector3.forward * offsetZ;
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref currentVelocity, damping);

    newPos = new Vector3 (newPos.x, Mathf.Clamp (newPos.y, yPosRestriction, Mathf.Infinity), newPos.z);

    transform.position = newPos;

    lastTargetPosition = target.position;       
}

void FindPlayer () {
    if (nextTimeToSearch <= Time.time) {
        GameObject searchResult = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        if (searchResult != null)
            target = searchResult.transform;
        nextTimeToSearch = Time.time + 0.5f;
    }
}
}
```

One of the main reasons I've been having problems with this is because I am quite new to Unity and have really only touched upon UnityScript, but my main problem is that as the rocket in my game's speed increases, the camera begins stuttering, I get the feeling that it is something to do with the dampening?

Comment: Have you tried using iTween? I've placed iTween scripts on camera and it helps the stuttering.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no necessity to find the player (`target`) inside `update()`. I assume that the GameObject behind the player will stay the same, so find the player **once** in the `Start()` method.

I'm not sure if that is the reason for your problem. You could trying out temporarily by setting the absolute value of 0.5f inside `FindPlayer()` to 0.02f or sth. This will update the target more often. If this helps, it's because you update the real target position only twice a second.

Comment: Once the target has been assigned the function you are referring to won't be called so, that's not the reason that thing is stuttering.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define the order in which you camera script and the movement of your target occur your camera can be a frame behind the action, which causes stuttering.

Change you camera script to:
`LateUpdate()` - if you are moving target yourself.
`FixedUpdate()` - if target is a Rigidbody moved by Physics.